# How to Print the Contents of an Array in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to print the contents of an array in Tcl (for debugging).  The order is unimportant, I just want every value printed.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [`parray`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1698):

```
% array set val [list a 1 b 2 c 3]
% parray val
val(a) = 1
val(b) = 2
val(c) = 3
```

If you want just the key and the value, well, use a loop and [`array get`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm#M8):

```
foreach {key value} [array get val] {
    puts "$key => $value"
}
```

Comment: `parray` is just a procedure; you can use `info body` to see how it works (it uses `array names`, `lsort`, `foreach` and `format`…)